# Search abbreviation from sentence in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to list the words that match the abbreviation. For an example, if I'm searching for **AI** or Artificial Intelligence then it should list for any record that contains 'Artificial Intelligence' as a part of the sentence. Similarly when I search for **MCA** or Master of Computer Application then it would list all the records which contain Master of Computer Application as a part of a sentence.

Assuming that my MySQL table is 'topics' with columns TopicID, TopicName, TopicDesc.
Sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77f8df

Note: I was asked to achieve it without additional table or column.

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: This is the sort of functionality which should be delivered through Full Text searching. Mysql InnoDB engine has that capability. [Find out more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/). However, it doesn't look like Mysql natively supports stemming or a customisable thesaurus, so you might be a bit limited in what you can achieve this way. But have a play around, it may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To search for abbreviations, use [`RLIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) with a regular expression. For instance, when searching for "MCA":

```
SELECT * FROM TOPICS WHERE
    TOPICNAME RLIKE '[[:<:]]M.*[[:<:]]C.*[[:<:]]A.*'
    OR 
    TOPICDESC RLIKE '[[:<:]]M.*[[:<:]]C.*[[:<:]]A.*'
```

Where `[[:<:]]` denotes the start of a word and `.*` matches any text character.

Note that there are some restrictions for Unicode characters as stated in the documentation, but as long as your text are in English you should be fine.

For a regular text search, use `LIKE` like with the text to be searched like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TOPICS WHERE
    TOPICNAME LIKE '%Master of Computer Application%'
    OR
    TOPICDESC LIKE '%Master of Computer Application%'
```